# Error inflating a custom view

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have a class called `MyCustomView` which extends `CardView` and implements `GestureDetectorCompat.OnGestureListener`.

When I inflate `MyCustomView` I keep receiving the following error:

```
Unable to start activity  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.ridever.scrollableviews.MyCardView
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
```

**Notice that:**

1. I have declared the package name in the layout file.
2. I have declared my domain name i.e. xmlns:app....
3. I have defined its 3 super class constructors.

After reading most post on this same issue I have no idea what is wrong. Any ideas?

Here is my code and layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/cardview"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    app:cardElevation="1dp">

    <!--ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/background"/-->

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


<com.ridever.scrollableviews.MyCardView
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-100dp"
    app:cardElevation="1dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/scrollable" />

</com.ridever.scrollableviews.MyCardView>
```

MyCardView definition here:

```
package com.ridever.scrollableviews;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class MyCardView extends CardView implements                 GestureDetector.OnGestureListener{
private static final String CTAG = "MyCardView";

private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetectorCompat;


public MyCardView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    gestureDetectorCompat = new GestureDetectorCompat(getContext(), this);
}

public MyCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetectorCompat) {
    super(context, attrs);
    gestureDetectorCompat = new GestureDetectorCompat(getContext(), this);

}

public MyCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetectorCompat) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    gestureDetectorCompat = new GestureDetectorCompat(getContext(), this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    gestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    final String MTAG = ".onFling()";
    Log.i(String.format("%s%s", CTAG, MTAG), "...");

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to remove extra parameters from  these two constructors?

```
public MyCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetectorCompat) {
```

and

```
public MyCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetectorCompat) {
```

By extra parameters I mean `GestureDetectorCompat` because you modify the contract that CardView has(by contract I mean available constructors) and I guess that Android is trying to instantiate your `MyCardView` using one of them.